# How do I control the data type in a specific PyQt5 QTableView column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt5, qtableview

(note: this is my first post here and I consider myself a "journeyman" at Python)

Problem summary:

- I have a PyQt5 QTableView populated by a pandas dataframe via an abstract table model
- A radio button group allows the user to switch the table between two dataframes
- Both dataframes confirm column 1 as an integer but the table view displays those numbers with a ".0" only for the dataframe that also contains other floating point numbers.
- I'd like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.
- The first dataframe contains all integers but the second dataframe only has integers in column 1 (the first non-index column)
- the first column is intended to be identical for both tables, as printing the dataframe contents confirms

dataframe self.freq_df

[image: freq dataframe print]
...

dataframe self.prob_df

[image: prob dataframe print]
...

- **However, when I use the radio button to switch to the second dataframe, it displays the integers as decimals to one place:**

Screenshot of prob table contents

[image: Screenshot of prob table contents]

Screenshot of prob table contents
[image: Screenshot of prob table contents]

Here are what I hope are the relevant code snippets:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None
```

```
        # layout 
        self.freq_table = QTableView(self)
        self.freq_tab.setLayout(self.freq_tab.layout)
```

```
self.freq_model = PandasModel(self.freq_df)
```

```
    self.prob_df = self.freq_df.copy()
    for col in range(1,8):
        probtemp = self.prob_df.iloc[:, col]/self.prob_df.iloc[:, col].sum()
        self.prob_df.iloc[:, col] = probtemp.round(decimals = 4)
    print(self.prob_df)
```

```
self.prob_model = PandasModel(self.prob_df)
```

radio button methods:

```
    def freqrad_update(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        if btn.isChecked()==True:
            self.freq_table.setModel(self.freq_model)
            
    def probrad_update(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        if btn.isChecked()==True:
            self.freq_table.setModel(self.prob_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Qt, but with pandas.

Specifically, the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) attribute, which returns a *numpy representation*. The values of numpy arrays must **always** be of the same type, and all the values of the dataframe will then be eventually converted to a suitable *common* type:

> Notes
>
> ---
>
> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with care if you are not dealing with the blocks.

In the second dataframe you are using mixed integers and floats, which makes the common data type float (presumably, `float64`).

If you are interested in the value itself, the numpy conversion is pointless, and you can use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) instead, which will return the actual value within the dataframe:

```py
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.at[index.row(), index.column()])
```

Note that the item notation is different, as it doesn't get items like in an array (a "list of lists"), but by using the `[row, col]` syntax.

Also note that returning `None` at the end of a function is pointless, since it's implicit in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @musicamente - and thanks for the tip about not needing "return none" (I had borrowed that model class). FYI when I replace the return line in the data method with 'return str(self._data.at[index.row(), index.column()])' , my tables are blank. I get no errors or warnings. I'll need to look deeper into what "at" is doing.

Comment: @zicari That may depend on the data types. Unfortunately, you only provided images for the data and we don't know from where it comes or how it was generated. For future reference, consider to provide a sample data or an explanation on how to obtain it.

Comment: Thanks again @musicamente - I edited my original and squeezed in the code where I generate the second dataframe from the first. you'll see that I iterate through all columns but the first, dividing each integer value by the column sum to get the resulting floats.

Comment: Then just use `iloc`. Also check that the value is properly represented by using the basic debugging tool: print it.

Comment: The second image in my original post (dataframe self.prop_df) is the result of '  print(self.prob_df)' immediately after creation. The first column appears to be an integer as needed. It's only when I load it into the table that it appears as a decimal. I also print the dataframe to check it after the table is populated and it still reports column 1 as an integer.

Comment: It appears as decimal as explained in my answer (and in the documentation): you must **not** use `values`, because that converts the dataframe to a numpy array and those arrays must *always* use the same data type. You have to print the value (and type) from the `data()` function, so that you understand if it is correct. Or, even more simpler, just add a print statement somewhere else for the first row/column value using `at` or `iloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Thanks so much to @musicamente for the help and for teaching me a little as well.

The solution was to replace the "values" call in the data method for my abstract table model class with "iloc" (with proper alteration of the row, column index format, of course.)

```
def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if index.isValid():
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(),index.column()])
```